# getting footnotes in reledmac to work with lettrine

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, lettrine

I started using `reledmac` a couple days ago and the documentation about footnotes already has me in tears.

I'm working on a thing using initial drop caps and small caps with `lettrine` and it so happens that the very first word in the book needs a footnote. I can't figure out how to do it without making the brackets intersect.

In this MWE, in my ideal world I can footnote just the word "Fubar." However, I'd be more than happy in a world where I could footnote "Fubar fizbutt." (Neither of those things may turn out to be possible, but, you know, it's 2020, I'm used to disappointment.)

Note that I don't really care what kind of footnotes (from among the hordes available in `reledmac`) I end up using.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{F}{ubar fizbutt} furball.

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question.... Do you need either critical or familiar footnote?

You must know that all the feature which change line skip (like lettrine) may cause trouble with reledmac.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't know that. So I'll just have to find another way to deal with it. (Just to clarify my question, in case it helps in some way: I'm trying to footnote either "Fubar" or "Fubar fizbutt"; it doesn't matter what kind of footnote (normal, critical, familiar) I use. But if I understand you correctly none of them is possible with lettrine, so I'll have to find a different way to approach the issue.) Thanks so much for the guidance!

Comment: WHat to do do mean by "to footnote something" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who's looking for this information and comes across this question: you can't use footnotes with `lettrine` in `reledmac`. Use `paracol` or something similar instead.